# Fixed point iteration method converging to infinity

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems, bisection

So I am trying to use Fixed Point Iteration Method for this function:

$ f(x)=x^5 -x^4-x-3 $ .

By using bisection method I found out that the root is around $1.64056$.

So I started by doing:

$f(x)=0$
then found out that:

$x=x^5-x^4-3$ .

So here I used Microsoft Excel and it generated very big numbers, which are converging to Inf almost instantly, even if I select my $x_0$ really close to my actual root I need to find. I am adding an Excel screenshot of what I am getting. Is it even possible to use Iteration method for this kind a function? If so,  where can I go from here?

[image]

Comment: What makes you think the fixed point is attractive?  The derivative of the right-hand side for $x$ approximately equal to the location of the root is bigger than $18$, so small errors in $x$ will be magnified by around $18$-times per iteration (and large errors can be multiplied by much larger factors).

Comment: I don't think that fixed point method is attractive, it's just an exact that which my professor appointed to me. So are you saying that it's impossible to find a root of this function by using this method?

Comment: Also, $1.5^5 - 1.5^4 - 3 = -0.4687{\dots}$, so the $n =1$ result in your spreadsheet is suspicious.  Perhaps you have the "${}-3$" twice?

Comment: A fixed point can be attractive or repulsive.  This fixed point is repulsive -- meaning that nearby points are pushed further away by the iteration.

Comment: Impossible?  No.  This can be done by fixed-point iteration, but not by moving the "$x$" to the left.

Comment: For instance, $x \leftarrow \sqrt[5]{x^4+x+3}$ is an iteration where the fixed point is attractive (determined by looking at the derivative of $\sqrt[5]{x^4+x+3}$ when $x$ is in$[1,2]$ and seeing that it is between $-1$ and $1$, so the map is a contraction on that interval).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I am trying to use Fixed Point Iteration Method for this function:
> $$f(x)=x^5 -x^4-x-3$$

To achieve what?

In case you want to find a zero of $f(x)$ by means of an iteration of the form
$$x\mapsto g(x)\qquad\text{where}\quad x_0=g(x_0)$$

$x_0$ is a fixed point of $g$, but it's only an [attractive fixed-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)#Attracting_fixed_points) (assuming $g$ is smooth) when $$|g'(x_0)|<1$$

You chose $g(x) = f(x) + x$ with $x_0\approx 1.64$, $g'(x) = 5x^4-4x^3$ and
$$g'(x_0)\approx18.55$$

Thus the fixed-point is clearly repelling.

You can use fixed-point iteration in principle, but as I wrote the absolute value of the derivative at the fixed-point must be less than one$^1$. So you'd have to construct some other function like
$$g(x) = \frac{x+3}{x^4} +1$$
(I did not check the derivative condition for this choice, though.$^3$)

[Newton-Raphson iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) usually works really well and has quadratic convergence$^2$, in your case:
$$x\mapsto x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} = x - \frac{x^5 -x^4-x-3}{5x^4 - 4x^3-1}$$
yields $x_0\approx 1.640585621426312$.

---

$^1$Equal to one is called "indifferent"; it might converge (slowly) but that case needs further analysis.

$^2$Provided you are "close" enough to the zero and it's not a multiple zero of $f$.

$^3$I did now and it's $-1.42$, so it won't work, either.

Comment: Thanks for recommendation, but I need to use this particular method. Are there any rules of constructing this new function or only that my derivative should be between $ [-1,1] $ ? And I have a question.  Let's say I take $ x0=0.1 $ Then my $ -1 < g'(x)=-0.0035 < 1 $, but it still does not work. How it can be that?

Comment: @Ugnius Švedas: No method I know of.  Pick one of the many $x$s, isolate it and check the derivative.  And you can "cheat" by splitting one $x$ in two by $x=tx+(1-t)x$, then isolate one $x$ and adjust $t$ such that the condition is satisfied (which may be not possible).  0.1 is **not** a fixed-point of $f$!

Comment: so my function does not have any fixed points? And why 0.1 is not a fixed point if the condition, that derivative is between -1 and 1 is confirmed? And also thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Ugnius Švedas: It does not matter whether $f$ has fixed-points or not.  What you want to do is find a function $g$ that 1) $g$ has a fixed-point at $x_0$ 2) $x_0$ is a zero of $f$ and 3) $|g'(x_0)|<1$.  That is, you transform the condition for "zero of $f$" to a condition for "$g$ has an attractive fixed-point at the zero of interest of $f$". As $f$ has only one zero over $\Bbb R$ which is that $x_0$, the only reasonable fixed-point for $g$ to consider is exactly that $x_0$.  It does not matter or help if $g$ has other fixed-points.

Answer (score 2):

In a polynomial with only one sign change in the coefficient sequence one can always find an equivalent form that is monotonous and convex or concave on the positive half-axis. With such a function it is known that the Newton iteration will converge monotonically towards the root if started on the right side of the root. This follows just from the geometry of the tangent as supporting line of the graph.

Here this can be achieved by dividing by $x^4$ or $x^5$. The first one gives
$f(x)=x-1-x^{-3}-3x^{-4}$, which is monotonically increasing and concave over the positive half-axis. Any tangent there is thus above the graph, tangent roots thus smaller than the function roots, but larger than the base point of the tangent. Then starting, for example, from $x_1=1$ the Newton iteration will be growing towards the root of the function.

The Newton method of $f$ to be used as fixed-point iteration is
$$N(x)=x-\frac{x-1-x^{-3}-3x^{-4}}{1+3x^{-4}+12x^{-5}}.$$

| $k$ | $x_k$ |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.0000000000000000 |
| 2 | 1.2500000000000000 |
| 3 | 1.4919752765802732 |
| 4 | 1.6203796983619547 |
| 5 | 1.6402369415053781 |
| 6 | 1.6405855189039007 |
| 7 | 1.6405856214263030 |
| 8 | 1.6405856214263119 |
| 9 | 1.6405856214263119 |

Comment: As I uderstood from a comment to the other answer, Newton-Raphson is not an option -- for whatever reason, presumably pedagogical.

Comment: Well, it is an iteration of the form $x_{+1}=g(x)=x-h(x)p(x)$, if $p$ is the original polynomial. And it has automatically $g'(x_*)=0$ for any root $x_*$, independent of what function is chosen as $f$. So it is quite hard to exclude the Newton iteration from the fixed-point iterations.